# how to exclude specific jar if possible from child module itself or war

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3

child module has below dependency so this alfresco-repository-5.1.1-tests.jar is coming that i can see in Maven dependencies in eclipse.I will use this jar only for compiling test classes.

```
<groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
```

I have parent module which will generate war which has this child module has dependency.so this jar is coming also in war.
    so how to exclude this jar in war?

Comment: If you war is using this a dependency and it contains it in the WAR the dependency is coming from somewhere else (may be as transitive dependency). You should check the war module via `mvn dependency:tree` and take a look at the tree...

Comment: Could not find goal 'tree' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo:dependency-maven-plugin:1.0 among available goals copy-dependencies, copy, unpack-dependencies, unpack -

Comment: this jar is coming from the child dependency only to the war.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of dependency-maven-plugin ? Which is from codehaus (ancient time) and not from [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). See here for all uptodate information about Apache Maven Plugins: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

1. When you package a Maven project to a WAR file, you don't package any dependencies mentioned within your pom.xml inside your WAR. your WAR file will include your pom.xml and your .class files in it, without dependencies.
2. If you need that dependency for testing purposes only, the test scope
   `<scope>test</scope>`
   is enough. That'll include the requested dependency in your classpath only when running your JUnits or any other tests. You can verify that if you'll execute the test phase & compile phase separately in debugging mode, and make sure that in test phase it's being included in your classpath, and in compile phase, it doesn't. To debug the test phase in command-line:

`mvn -X test`